# Removing deleted images from Interface Builder dropdown

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I deleted some image files from my project, but they are still available to select via the dropdown in Xcode when I'm working in Interface Builder. Is there a quick and easy way to remove them for selection in the dropdown as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try deleting them from your project directory on disk?

Comment: By that I'm assuming you mean outside of Xcode in my project folder. Yes, they are not located in there either. This isn't a huge deal just a minor annoyance. It just seems like they shouldn't be available any longer to select.

Answer (score 0):

It does get removed from IB also in my case.
Can you post a screen shot of the problem.

Comment: I'm unable to attach an image as I do not have enough "points" yet. I'm simply able to select to use an image that is no longer in my project.